# How can I get visible item index from scrolling position from FlatList in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a horizontal FlatList where I render a collection, now I want to know which item is into view (index) taking into account that each item width is almost equal to device width, lets say 400, how can I get visible item index on my `onScroll` method?

```
<FlatList scrollEventThrottle={16} onScroll={handleScroll} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={{ width:'100%', '}} 
        horizontal={true} data={categories} keyExtractor={item => item.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => 
            <TouchableOpacity  style={{ width:400,height:275 }}>{ item }</Text> 
            </TouchableOpacity>}
        />
```

`handleScroll` method:

```
const handleScroll = (event) => {
        console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x);
       
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use FlatList onViewableItemsChanged prop to get what you want.

```html
  const _onViewableItemsChanged = React.useCallback(({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
    console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems);
    console.log("Changed in this iteration, ", changed);
  }, []);

  const _viewabilityConfig = {
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 60
  }
  
  
  
  
   <FlatList
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        horizontal={true}
        data={categories}
        onViewableItemsChanged={_onViewableItemsChanged}
        viewabilityConfig={_viewabilityConfig}
        keyExtractor={item => item.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: 400, height: 275 }}><Text>{item}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>}
      />
```

viewabilityConfig can help you to make whatever you want with viewability settings. In code example 60 means that item is considered visible if it is visible for more than 60 percents.